# Mysql result dataset filter issue

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to filter result as follows:

Dataset:

```
ID          NAME            VALUE
-----------------------------------------
23          Test            TRUE
24          Test            FALSE
25          Test            FALSE
26          Test            TRUE
27          Test            FALSE
28          Test            FALSE
```

Result should be:

```
ID          NAME            VALUE
-----------------------------------------
23          Test            TRUE
24          Test            FALSE
26          Test            TRUE
27          Test            FALSE
```

The idea is to return all rows that has value TRUE and first row that has value of false after true

Comment: you have to do it in code level

Comment: Will there always be a false value after true? or could there be 2 true after each other

Comment: @kranthi Why???

Comment: @Strawberry: there we don't have any condition to specify.....

Comment: @kranthi I don't follow.

Comment: @RealCheeseLord there could be multiple true without false

Comment: @Strawberry because I receive multiple events when states change but I need to show result only when status changed in first place, so basically I receive time to time event false but I need to show only when this state really changed from true to false

Comment: @ShpetimShala It's OK - I wasn't talking to you !

Answer (score 0):

Probably only with joining table to same table again, only problem with this sql is that it needs to have non-breaking `ID`

> Data
>
> ```
> id    name    value   
> 1     TEST    1   
> 2     TEST    0   
> 3     TEST    0   
> 4     TEST    0   
> 5     TEST    1   
> 6     TEST    1   
> 7     TEST    0   
> 8     TEST    0   
> 9     TEST    1
> ```

Join same table based on id from next row and then all rows from table where value `true/1` or current row is `t1.value=0` and previous `t2.value = 1`

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table as t1 
LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t1.id = t2.id + 1 
WHERE ( ( t1.value = 1 ) OR ( t1.value = 0 AND t2.value = 1 ) )
ORDER BY t1.id
```

> Result
>
> ```
> id    name    value   
> 1     TEST    1   
> 2     TEST    0   
> 5     TEST    1   
> 6     TEST    1   
> 7     TEST    0   
> 9     TEST    1
> ```

**EDIT:**  My last chance, though not sure performance but noncontinous id are working with this

```
SELECT * FROM my_table as t1 
LEFT JOIN my_table t2 ON
t2.id = (
   SELECT MAX(my_table.id) FROM my_table
   WHERE my_table.id < t1.id ORDER BY id asc LIMIT 1
) 
WHERE (t1.value=1) OR (t1.value=0 AND t2.value=1) order by t1.id asc
```

Comment: not possible on my case because id's are not "not-braked" ID, I have result with id 3, 8, 22, etc. :(

Comment: Next time you can write about these result id in question that they arent continuous :) @ShpetimShala

Answer (score 0):

I guess this could be done with a self join, something like:

```
   SELECT ID, NAME, VALUE
     FROM table
    WHERE VALUE = "TRUE"
UNION ALL
   SELECT t2.ID, t2.NAME, t2.VALUE
     FROM table t1
     JOIN table t2
       ON t1.ID +1 = t2.ID
      AND t1.VALUE = "TRUE"
      AND t2.VALUE = "FALSE"
```

EDIT: this also only works for nonebreaking IDs, so not usable for OPs case

Comment: "ON t1.ID +1 = t2.ID" this part wont work on my case, ID's are not not braked

Comment: @ShpetimShala can you `CREATE` temp tables? If yes you could create your own  table with consecutive IDs and Use mine or Mareks Code

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,value TINYINT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(23,'Test',TRUE),
(24,'Test',FALSE),
(25,'Test',FALSE),
(26,'Test',TRUE),
(27,'Test',FALSE),
(28,'Test',FALSE);

SELECT a.* 
  FROM my_table a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , MIN(y.id) minid 
         FROM my_table x 
         JOIN my_table y 
           ON y.id > x.id 
          AND y.value = FALSE 
        WHERE x.value = TRUE 
        GROUP 
           BY x.id
     ) b 
    ON a.id IN (b.id,b.minid);
+----+------+-------+
| id | name | value |
+----+------+-------+
| 23 | Test |     1 |
| 24 | Test |     0 |
| 26 | Test |     1 |
| 27 | Test |     0 |
+----+------+-------+
```